# list directory entries in the svn repository?

Tags: linux, svn

How can I write a bash script to list directory entries in the svn repository?
I want to write bash file because i have a large number of repositories.

Comment: When will people stop writing "HELP ME" :/ @Mohammad: Clarify your question. What exactly is it you want to do?

Comment: i write help me because i start to learn linux after 2 days ... and i have big work in it and in the following comment clear explain of my problem

Comment: ok ... see the following example.... i do the following :- execute the this command to find the repository :- "sudo find / -type f -name fs-type -print " the following result appear :- "/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/impl/VJ/resources /var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/impl/JKB/code/iris" and more maybe 500 repository now i want to show content of each repository for Followed in the next comment >>

Comment: now i want to find the content of each repository for example :-"/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core" so i execute this command :- "svn list svn+ssh://svn.sts.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core" but i have maybe 500 repository it is very complex to execute it for each one ...Taking into account each one require password –

Comment: please i want to ask you .... no body answer this question WHY ? ... i ask more than "20" person and the same answer "i don't know" ... please i need the answer as soon as possible :(

Comment: Removed "solaris" and "repository" tags. Question has nothing to do with these areas

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are the subversion administrator, the following command will return the directories located in your repository.

```
svnlook tree $REPO_DIR --full-paths | egrep "/$"
```

The trick is the grep command that is looking for a trailing "/" character in the name

Same trick works for the svn command as well

```
svn list $REPO_URL -R | egrep "/$"
```

### Extra notes

To repeatedly run this command you can put it into a shell for loop

```
for url in $URL1 $URL2 $URL2
do
svn list $url -R | egrep "/$"
done
```

Comment: i try it now but the follwing result appear:-
svnlook: invalid option: --full-paths
Type 'svnlook help' for usage.

Comment: I'm using subversion 1.6.6. Doco: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnlook.c.tree.html

Comment: when i execute svn list $REPO_URL -R | egrep "/$" the following result 
svn: '.' is not a working copy

Comment: Yes.... And I get the same result when running the following command: "svn list $I_SHOULD_REPLACE_THIS_WITH_MY_OWN_URL_LOCATION -R". Please use a valid subversion URL when running the command

Comment: iam sorry i don't have expert in this field ... and i under big press... you mean like this "svn list $/var/lib/svn/repos -R | egrep "/$" " if you mean this the following result appearsvn: '$/var/lib/svn' is not a working copy

Comment: No... What command are you using when checking out from the repository? Send it to me and I'll convert it for you

Comment: ok i use the following command (svn list svn+ssh://svn.sts.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos -R | egrep "/$" )

Comment: i hope to give me you e-mail to chat you on MSN ... but no problem ..it is work but i have a many many repository if i want to execute each one like this method it is a hard method because i have more than 500 repository ... so i need method to execute all at the same time .. for examlpe write bash ... thank you for help me

Comment: You're welcome. It's customary on stackoverflow to accept the answer that works.

Comment: but please how i can find List directory entries in big number of the svn repository

Comment: @Franck Answer 8 years old. Apologies, I haven't used subversion in a long time. I can't delete an accepted answer

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I found my solution. `egrep` is not working but `grep` is. Here the [link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48955498/2748412)