# How can I "clip" the output of the find command?

Tags: linux, svn

I executed the following command:

```
find / -type f -name fs-type -exec svnlook tree {} \; |egrep "/$"
```

The result was

```
svnlook: Can't open file '/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core/db/fs-type/format': Not a directory 
svnlook: Can't open file '/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees/db/fs-type/format': Not a directory
```

Maybe I should make `find` command give me the path without `db/fs-type/format` in other words I should clip the output of `find`. How can I do this?

Comment: May be you can give more details about what you like to achieve?

Comment: 1. i want find all repository .... 2. i want find entire directory for all repository .... note : the result of execute step one more than 500 repositoy so i need method to execute step two by easy

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745744/list-directory-entries-in-the-svn-repository

Comment: Removed "repository" "solaris" and "ubuntu" tags. This question is a problem invoking a subversion admin comment from the unix find command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can give

```
find ... -not -path "*/db/*"
```

to find.

Comment: it is not work the followin result appear:
find: bad option -not
find: path-list predicate-list

Comment: That sound like not having a GNU find ? (Are you working on solaris?)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for

```
find Subversion -type d -name db -exec svnlook tree {}/.. \; | egrep "/$"
```

Your command was failing because svnlook expects a directory argument not a file one.