# Getting list of all folders but not the files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to use the svn commands to gather all folders and subfolders from svn. The list is huge.

I have tried making an empty folder on svn and compare it with the base but it crashes after 4 hours.

I have tried the following this morning :

```
svn list --depth infinity http://serverip/svn/root/
```

and it has been running for nearly 6 hours so far and still not finished and it lists all the files.

I tried on the side a couple other ways with `grep` and `egrep` parameters but it is not recognized so i believe they might be Bash commands and i am on windows so that would explain why it's not doing anything good.

All i want is all folders and subfolders within the root. And if possible with the command i would filter on specific folder names like "/tag-088/121359/". If i cannot filter in the command it's not a big deal it's very easy to filter myself within excel or something like that. The main goal is to only pick folder and subfolder and not files.

I have about 4.2 terabyte svn so it is a bit slow probably because of that so that is why i am trying to list without the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the server (which I assume you do, given that you know well the size of the repository), you might consider using the `svnlook` program.  Like `svn`, `svnlook` offers a collection of subcommands.  You'll want the `svnlook tree` subcommand, and specifically the `--full-paths` option which causes it to print its output one-path-per-line instead of using a nested/indented approach.  Piped through a `grep` that keeps only output which ends in a slash character (true only of directory paths), you'll have the list you seek.

```
$ svnlook tree /path/to/repos --full-paths | grep '/$'
/
/trunk/
/trunk/dir/
/trunk/otherdir/
/tags/
/tags/my-tag/
/tags/my-tag/dir/
/tags/my-tag/otherdir/
...
```

Comment: I ran it completely and It was a success. It took ~5 hours and it was complete. It would have ran for couple extra days if i had use the standard list command without the filtering out the files. Thanks again.

Comment: how to filter only two folders means one and his subfolders  exp `trunk/dir/` and not `/trunk/dir/dir2`